# Can you make thin crispy dosa without urad dal?? Can I use any other lentils in their place?

Tags: substitutions

I live in Finland and I can't find urad dal in the city where I live.

Can I make thin crispy dosa with different beans?

Comment: Just to be pedantic- technically urad dal is not a lentil. Translations from Indian languages tend to be a little off in reference to beans. I blame Google Translate.

Comment: This question makes me want to try making dosa with pinto beans and see  if it interests or horrifies my Indian coworkers.

Comment: Is there any store carrying TRS brand ingredients in your city? They might be able to order it for you...

Answer (score 3):

Urad dal is the most common legume used in traditional dosa recipes but it is by no means the only legume used.

Recipes for traditional dosa will sometimes use other high protein legumes such as chana dal. This variety of chickpea, or other chickpea varieties, may be easier to find.

My experience with Scandinavian countries leads me to believe that legumes in general are much less popular. You might have better luck just ordering urad dal online.

Answer (score 2):

You could always make [Rava Dosa](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rava_dosa) - it's made with semolina and rice flour.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately a traditional dosa recipe calls for urad dal. But since u can't avail it, u can prepare dosa using wheat flour, or a simple rava dosa using sooji as main ingredient.
There is a special dosa called neer dosa which is a regional recipe from Karnataka state of India.
It uses only rice luckily. Grind rice along with some fresh shredded coconut and salt to a thin batter. Mix water to make it even more thinner. It shouldn't coat the back of the laddle. It's the correct consistency. Make dosas with it . Swirl the dosa pan rather than spreading the batter by laddle. But you ll get soft dosas only. Hope this helps. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I make it with [chana dal](https://www.veganricha.com/indian-dals-names) (split chickpeas) or green split hulled dal as a substitute to urad by choice.